# How to allocate a string before you know how big it needs to be

Tags: string, rust, lifetime

I'm sure this is a beginners mistake.  My code is:

```
...
let mut latest_date : Option<Date<Local>> = None;
let mut latest_datetime : Option<DateTime<Local>> = None;
let mut latest_activity : Option<&str> = None;

for wrapped_line in reader.lines() {
    let line = wrapped_line.unwrap();
    println!("line: {}", line);

    if date_re.is_match(&line) {
        let captures = date_re.captures(&line).unwrap();
        let year = captures.at(1).unwrap().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        let month = captures.at(2).unwrap().parse::<u32>().unwrap();
        let day = captures.at(3).unwrap().parse::<u32>().unwrap();
        latest_date = Some(Local.ymd(year, month, day));
        println!("date: {}", latest_date.unwrap());
    }

    if time_activity_re.is_match(&line) && latest_date != None {
        let captures = time_activity_re.captures(&line).unwrap();
        let hour = captures.at(1).unwrap().parse::<u32>().unwrap();
        let minute = captures.at(2).unwrap().parse::<u32>().unwrap();
        let activity = captures.at(3).unwrap();

        latest_datetime = Some(latest_date.unwrap().and_hms(hour, minute, 0));

        latest_activity = if activity.len() > 0 {
            Some(activity)
        } else {
            None
        };

        println!("time activity: {} |{}|", latest_datetime.unwrap(), activity);
    }
}
...
```

My error is:

```
   Compiling tt v0.1.0 (file:///home/chris/cloud/tt)
src/main.rs:69:55: 69:59 error: `line` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:69             let captures = time_activity_re.captures(&line).unwrap();
                                                                     ^~~~
src/main.rs:55:5: 84:6 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:53:51: 86:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 7 at 53:50...
src/main.rs:53     let mut latest_activity : Option<&str> = None;
src/main.rs:54 
src/main.rs:55     for wrapped_line in reader.lines() {
src/main.rs:56         let line = wrapped_line.unwrap();
src/main.rs:57         println!("line: {}", line);
src/main.rs:58 
               ...
src/main.rs:56:42: 84:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 56:41
src/main.rs:56         let line = wrapped_line.unwrap();
src/main.rs:57         println!("line: {}", line);
src/main.rs:58 
src/main.rs:59         if date_re.is_match(&line) {
src/main.rs:60             let captures = date_re.captures(&line).unwrap();
src/main.rs:61             let year = captures.at(1).unwrap().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
               ...
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `tt`.
```

I think the problem is that the `latest_activity : Option<&str>` lives longer than `line` inside the loop iteration where `latest_activity` is reassigned.

Is the correct?

If so, what's the best way of fixing it.  The cost of allocating a new string does not bother me, though I would prefer not to do that for each iteration.

I feel I may need a reference-counted box to put the `activity` in - is this the right approach?

I could allocate a `String` outside of the loop - but how can I do so before I know how big it will need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *already* allocating a new string for every iteration (there's nowhere for the `Lines` iterator to store a buffer, so it has to allocate a fresh `String` for each line), but you're trying to store a slice into it outside the loop.

You also can't really know how big an externally allocated `String` would need to be in this case... so typically you wouldn't worry about it and just resize as necessary.

The *simplest* way is probably to make `latest_activity` an `Option<String>`.  When you want to *change* it, you can use `.clear()` followed by `.push_str(s)` (see the [`String` documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html)).  This should re-use the existing allocation if it's large enough, resizing if it isn't.  It might require some re-allocating, but nothing major (provided you don't, for example, try to store increasingly longer and longer strings).

Another possibility would be to just store `wrapped_line` itself, moving it out of the loop.  You could store that alongside the slice indices, and then do the *actual* slicing outside the loop (no, you can't just store the `String` and the `&str` slice separately *or* together with just standard library types).