# How can I wrap the read portion of a struct which implements both Read and Write in a BufReader?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrow

I am trying to read a line from a `rustls::StreamOwned` object. My first instinct was to wrap it in a `BufReader`, but the problem is that I need to be able to interleave my `read_line()` calls with `write()` calls, and I cannot use the underlying stream while `BufReader` has a mutable reference to it. What is the idiomatic way to solve this problem?

Sample Code:

```
let stream: rustls::StreamOwned = //blah
let r = BufReader::new(stream) // Can't pass a reference here since &rustls::StreamOwned doesn't implement the read trait
loop {
    let line: String;
    r.read_line(&line);
    stream.write(b"ping"); // Will fail to compile since r still owns the stream
}
```

Similar Question:

[How to use a file with a BufReader and still be able to write to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831265/how-to-use-a-file-with-a-bufreader-and-still-be-able-to-write-to-it)

The difference is that the reference type of the type I am dealing with does not implement the `Read` trait, so I cannot simply pass a reference to the `BufReader`.

Comment: Implement `Read` for a reference to `RefCell` to the type?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem comes from the realization that `BufReader` does not contain a `Read` value, but a generic type that implements `Read`. In your case that is a literal `StreamOwned`, the actual type is not lost because you use a BufReader, or should I say a `BufReader<StreamOwned>`.

And you can access the inner value with [`BufReader::get_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.get_mut). There is a note in the documentation that says:

> It is inadvisable to directly read from the underlying reader.

Which makes sense because that direct read would mess up the buffered stream, but it says nothing about using other non-read features of the contained object, as in your case the writing half of the stream.

TL;DR: write something like ([mocked playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77b7e4df510d6c8288df91de94864c17)):

```
fn main() {
    let stream = StreamOwned;
    let mut r = BufReader::new(stream);
    loop {
        let mut line = String::new();
        r.read_line(&mut line);
        r.get_mut().write(b"ping"); // now it compiles!
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there was no confusion about BufReader  containing a 'type that implements read', hence why I wrote "does not implement the Read trait" in my original question. `Which makes sense because that direct read would mess up the buffered stream,` I understand why BufReader needs exclusive access to the underlying reader, but that isn't my problem. `r.get_mut().write(b"ping");` is indeed the solution, but it seems a bit kludgy to create a mutable reference to the underlying object each time I want to use it mutably.

Comment: @curious: Yes, I admit it looks a bit kludgy. If you use that a lot, or if you want a `BufWriter` for it, it might make sense to create a _newtype_ wrapping `BufReader<StreamOwned>` and implement `BufRead` and `Write` for it. But for regular use, I think this is just _good enough_.